# JPA Many to many unidirectional

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I use spring data jpa and i try to do a many to many unidirectional relation.

```
@Entity
public class Appartment {
   ...
   @ManyToMany
   private List<AppartmentFeatureOption> featureOption;
} 

@Entity
public class AppartmentFeatureOption {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long appartmentFeatureOptionId;

  private String name;

  private BigDecimal value;
}
```

My database is created at run time, but i get this error

org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Same physical table name [appartment_feature_option] references several logical table names: [AppartmentFeatureOption], [Appartment_AppartmentFeatureOption]

Any idea?

Edit with this code that work

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="appartment_feautre_option_appartment", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="appartment_id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="appartment_feautre_option_id"))  
private List<AppartmentFeatureOption> featureOption;
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this is actually your real code, maybe the issue is that you are using a *ManyToMany* relationship between *Appartment* and *AppartmentFeatureOption* whereas there is no link to *Appartment* in the *AppartmentFeatureOption*.

From my understanding for one **Appartment** you want to have several **AppartmentFeatureOption**, which is a **OneToMany** relationship.

Comment: An one to many will not work, same option can be used in different appartment.

Comment: Yes but... One to many means that for one apartment you can have several options

Comment: If there is a business value in being able to retrieve _apartments_ from _options_, then you need a ManyToMany relationship, if not it is a OneToMany... Still, I'm glad you found the answer to your question in the end ;)

Comment: I don't understand why  you worry about duplication. In both cases the relationship will result in a join table holding only IDs from the _Apartment_ & _ApartmentFeatureOptions_. The join table ID will be the pair _(AppartmentId,AppartmentFeatureId)_

Comment: with many to many and one to many, the created table is not really the same.